# How can I make the Ubuntu dock smaller vertically?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I am on GNOME 3.28, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I want to go from the default 18.04 dock which spans the full vertical of the screen, to no wasted space like the following:

[image: this]

Is it possible to do this in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: `sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` and go from there. Or `sudo apt install dconf-editor` and then use Dconf Editor to customize the shell extension (Dash to Dock as far as Dconf is concerned) to your taste.